# Bring the application to the front - application unknown in advance?

Tags: vba

I have this sub to open a file - it choose the appropriate application for the file and it works nicely:

```
Public Sub OpenNativeApp(ByVal psDocName As String)

    ' Opens the files psDocName in the appropriate application
    Dim r As Long, msg As String

    r = StartDoc(psDocName)

    If r <= 32 Then  

        'There was an error
        Select Case r
            Case SE_ERR_FNF
                msg = "File not found"
            Case SE_ERR_PNF
                msg = "Path not found"
            Case SE_ERR_ACCESSDENIED
                msg = "Access denied"
            Case SE_ERR_OOM
                msg = "Out of memory"
            Case SE_ERR_DLLNOTFOUND
                msg = "DLL not found"
            Case SE_ERR_SHARE
                msg = "A sharing violation occurred"
            Case SE_ERR_ASSOCINCOMPLETE
                msg = "Incomplete or invalid file association"
            Case SE_ERR_DDETIMEOUT
                msg = "DDE Time out"
            Case SE_ERR_DDEFAIL
                msg = "DDE transaction failed"
            Case SE_ERR_DDEBUSY
                msg = "DDE busy"
            Case SE_ERR_NOASSOC
                msg = "No association for file extension"
            Case ERROR_BAD_FORMAT
                msg = "Invalid EXE file or error in EXE image"
            Case Else
                msg = "Unknown error"
        End Select

        MsgBox msg

    End If

End Sub
```

But how can I change the code so the application brings itself into front on the screen ?

Comment: You need to also show us StartDoc. Without that it's impossible to say. Also tell us which kinds of file types these *could* be.

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, here you got it:

Private Function StartDoc(psDocName As String) As Long
    Dim Scr_hDC As Long
    Scr_hDC = GetDesktopWindow()
    StartDoc = ShellExecute(Scr_hDC, "Open", psDocName, "", "C:\", SW_SHOWNORMAL)
End Function